# i want to have it sum together the value of ABC

Tags: oracle

```
        select distinct
  dsp_sku
,decode (cc.stat_code, '0', 'Unprocessed', '90', 'Processed', '99', 'Expired') as Status,
  trunc(cc.create_date_time) CC_date,
  case
    when dsp_sku = 'EGIA60AMT' then 'A'
    when dsp_sku = 'LF1937' then 'A'
    when dsp_sku = '980X3ENDIUU' then 'A'
when dsp_sku = 'VP521X' then 'B'
    when dsp_sku = 'FT6009' then 'B'
    when dsp_sku = '125037' then 'B'
  when dsp_sku = 'CG925' then 'C'
    when dsp_sku = 'SPGR101351' then 'C'
    when dsp_sku = 'CL14MG' then 'C'
when dsp_sku = '603011825' then 'D'
    when dsp_sku = '603011827' then 'D'
    when dsp_sku = '603011828' then 'D'
    else null
  end as ABC_Value
from WH_GHC1.CYCLE_COUNT_HIST cc
  left join item_master im on
    im.sku_id = cc.sku_id
  inner join locn_hdr lh on
    lh.locn_id = cc.locn_id
where
  cc.whse = 'PH3'
  --and cc.stat_code in ('0','90') --stat_code: 0 is unprocessed, 90 is processed, 99 is expired
  and cc.stat_code = 90
  --and cc.stat_code = 0
  --and cc.create_date_time between '&FromDate' and '&EndDate'
  and
  cc.create_date_time > '&StartDate'
--and dsp_sku = '&SKU'
  --and not im.srl_nbr_reqd = 4
  --and EXPTD_QTY = 0
  --and actl_invn_qty = 0
```

ive tried a sum statement with not luck any recommendations?
this is the smaller version of the query, the original query has a lot more lines of the ABC case when statement.

Comment: What do you want to do? As written, it sounds like you want to sum a bunch of letters. Please include sample data and sample expected output and edit the question so we can better understand what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I assigned each SKU with a letter. how can I have it sum together the total number of A value b's and etc...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, that would be

```
  SELECT dsp_sku,
         DECODE (cc.stat_code,
                 '0', 'Unprocessed',
                 '90', 'Processed',
                 '99', 'Expired')
            AS status,
         TRUNC (cc.create_date_time) cc_date,
         CASE
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'EGIA60AMT' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'LF1937' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '980X3ENDIUU' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'VP521X' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'FT6009' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '125037' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'CG925' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'SPGR101351' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'CL14MG' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011825' THEN 'D'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011827' THEN 'D'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011828' THEN 'D'
            ELSE NULL
         END
            AS abc_value,                                                   --
         COUNT (*)                                                    --> this
    FROM ...
GROUP BY dsp_sku,
         DECODE (cc.stat_code,
                 '0', 'Unprocessed',
                 '90', 'Processed',
                 '99', 'Expired'),
         TRUNC (cc.create_date_time),
         CASE
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'EGIA60AMT' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'LF1937' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '980X3ENDIUU' THEN 'A'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'VP521X' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'FT6009' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '125037' THEN 'B'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'CG925' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'SPGR101351' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = 'CL14MG' THEN 'C'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011825' THEN 'D'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011827' THEN 'D'
            WHEN dsp_sku = '603011828' THEN 'D'
            ELSE NULL
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a numeric column to sum so I am assuming you wish to count the number of each type of `abc_value` then you just need to take your query and nest it in another query where you can perform the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT abc_value,
       COUNT(*) AS num_abc_values
FROM   (
  <your_large_query>
)
GROUP BY abc_value
```

Comment: how would I add another column to count only the variances?

Comment: im using this case when statement to calculate the variances {case
    when EXPTD_QTY <> ACTL_INVN_QTY then (EXPTD_QTY-ACTL_INVN_QTY)*(-1)       how would I add a column to sum them together...?
    else null
  end as variance_}

Comment: Add those two columns to your large query's output (which may affect the number of rows from `DISTINCT` clause) and then use `SUM( CASE WHEN exptd_qty <> actl_invn_qty THEN .... END ) AS variance` in the outer query. However, that is outside the scope of the question you asked here so if it doesn't do quite what you want then you will need to ask a new question about that specific point as it is off topic for this question.